# start-all.sh, start-dfs.sh command not found

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and installed hadoop 2.7.2. The Output of

> hadoop version

is

> Hadoop 2.7.2
>   Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b165c4fe8a74265c792ce23f546c64604acf0e41
>   Compiled by jenkins on 2016-01-26T00:08Z
>   Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
>   From source with checksum d0fda26633fa762bff87ec759ebe689c
>   This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar

and when i run

> whereis hadoop

it gives output as

> hadoop: /usr/local/hadoop /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop.cmd /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop

But when i run command

> start-all.sh

it says command not found.
also when i run

> start-dfs.sh

it gives output as command not found.

I am able to run these command when i navigate to hadoop directory but i want to run these command without navigating into hadoop directory.

Comment: Do you mean it works when you are in the `/usr/local/hadoop` directory / does `/usr/local/hadoop/start-all.sh` work?

Comment: Its works in >/usr/local/hadoop/sbin  by command './start-all.sh' not by 'start-all.sh'

Comment: What do you get with an `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Output of echo $PATH is /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/

Comment: Ok. I think I got this...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that bash doesn't know where to look for `./start-all.sh`.

You can fix this by opening `$HOME/.bashrc` and **adding** a line that looks like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin
```

This tells bash that it should look in '/usr/local/hadoop/sbin' for `start-all.sh`.

***Note:***

Changes to `$HOME/.bashrc` will not take affect in any terminals that are *currently* open.

If you need the changes to take affect in a terminal that is currently open, run

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: In the $HOME/.bashrc file the last lines were export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin/
I have changed the last line of path to PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin as you said but not get the result

Comment: Oh Thanks. I was running it in the same terminal. I just reopened my terminal and now it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to help, and grateful that you remembered to accept the answer. (Some people never accept an answer and just leave the question alone once they got their problem fixed.) Have a good one.

Comment: I always appreciate you people always eager to help you deserve a lot more than this. I owe you for helping me out. Thanks again and have a nice day.

Comment: I had a new problem ocurred from your solution. Now my hadoop version command is not working.

Comment: I wandered if something like that might happen... Did you keep the lines that were in '$HOME/.bashrc' or did you delete them?

Comment: I replaced the export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin line with export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to search for it with find.

```
find / -iname start-all.sh 2>  /dev/null
```

It found:

```
/usr/local/sbin/start-all.sh
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.4/libexec/sbin/start-all.sh
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.4/sbin/start-all.sh
```

So in addition to the previous answer, the variable in `$HOME/.bashrc` looks like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin/
```

Note: I'm not sure which one should be set as `PATH`